# MySQL Stored Proc's Param with IN Varchar() not looping the cursor

Tags: mysql, csv, stored-procedures

I am trying to get the following to work while testing `Stored Procedures`, but it doesnt. Can someone point out whats wrong?

The idea is to take in a list of `userids` as csv, and return their `email addresses` as csv.

(This is just for testing stored proc. in mysql. I know I could just simply select it with regular sql query)

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `build_email_list`$$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `testing_email_list`(IN user_ids VARCHAR(200), INOUT email_list VARCHAR(4000))
BEGIN

    DECLARE v_finished INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE v_email VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT "";     

    DECLARE email_cursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT email_address FROM users WHERE id IN (user_ids);

    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET v_finished = 1;

    OPEN email_cursor;     
    get_email: LOOP

        FETCH email_cursor INTO v_email;     
        IF v_finished = 1 THEN LEAVE get_email; END IF;      
        SET email_list = CONCAT(v_email, ";", email_list);

    END LOOP get_email;

CLOSE email_cursor;     
END$$    
DELIMITER ;
```

Calling it like this:

```
SET @email_list = "";
CALL testing_email_list("1,8", @email_list);
SELECT @email_list;
```

However, it only returns the first id passed (i.e. `1`). But when I change the stored proc to directly take these ids with the following it works fine:

```
DECLARE email_cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT email_address FROM users WHERE id IN (1,8);
```

This is driving me nuts, what am I missing here?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You must use [SQL Syntax 13.5 for Prepared Statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html), your query runs like this: `SELECT email_address FROM users WHERE id IN ('1, 8');`. You can avoid CURSOR, using [GROUP_CONCAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function.

Comment: this is just an example of the actually a bigger and more complex procedure I have to run..

Comment: The solution is more complicated, because you need a cursor of a dynamic query, to do this I recommend reading the following article: [MariaDB / MySQL: Cursors for Dynamic SQL](https://falseisnotnull.wordpress.com/2013/01/08/mariadbmysql-cursors-for-dynamic-sql/).

Comment: oh boy... thats too long..

Comment: That is why I try to avoid a cursor when they should be generated from a dynamic query, there is much to do.